# Laravel 5.3 - Win10 - PHPUnit - Test code or tested code did not (only) close its own output buffers

Tags: php, laravel, phpunit

Laravel 5.3, windows 10, VS code.
PHPUnit is marking the simplest of tests as 'Risky'. 
Any ideas why?

I've tried all sorts of PHPUnit settings to switch of that 'Risky' output buffers error and this is the simplest test so I'm unsure where to start as to why it's happening.

VS Code terminal output...

```
C:/Source/laravel/vendor/bin/phpunit.bat -v -c
C:/Source/laravel/phpunit.xml ./laravel/tests/ExampleTest.php PHPUnit
5.6.2 by Sebastian Bergmann and contributors.

Runtime:       PHP 7.0.12 with Xdebug 2.4.1 Configuration:
C:\Source\laravel\phpunit.xml R                                       
1 / 1 (100%) Time: 562 ms, Memory: 28.00MB There was 1 risky test: 1)
ExampleTest::testBasicExample Test code or tested code did not (only)
close its own output buffers
```

Controller.

```
    <?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;

class TestController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * Create a new controller instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
    }

    public function index()
    {
        return 'OK';
    }
}
```

Test

```
    <?php

use Illuminate\Foundation\Testing\WithoutMiddleware;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Testing\DatabaseMigrations;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Testing\DatabaseTransactions;

class ExampleTest extends TestCase
{
    /**
     * A basic functional test example.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function testBasicExample()
    { 
        $this->visitRoute('test')
              ->seeText('OK');
    }
}
```

Route:

```
Route::get('/test', 'TestController@index')->name('test');
```

Answer (score 0):

I just figured this out... the issue was with the TestCase 'requiring/including' the wp-load.php file as I use some wordpress functions within my controllers. Remove that and it's fine.